# Why is the von Neumann entropy maximised when $p_n=1/N$?

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

For example, $\hat \rho=\sum_{\substack{n}} p_n |E_n \rangle \langle E_n|$ is a stationary mixed state of a given quantum system, where $|E_n \rangle$ are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $\hat H$ with the eigenvalues $E_n$.

In every book that I read on quantum information, it says that $p_n=1/N$ for the maximal value of the von Neumann entropy for the given mean energy.

I don't see how we could end up with this value. And I would like to understand how to prove that.

Any references to books/websites where I can read about the derivation is also much appreciated.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check Schur-concavity.

Comment: $p_n=1/N$ is the maximal value of the entropy *without* constraining the mean energy. If you constrain the mean energy, $p_n=1/N$ might not even be a possible probability distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant the say that $p_n=1/N$ is the maximal value of the von Neumann entropy *without* constraining the mean energy (otherwise the statement is not true).

One way to see it is using Lagrange multipliers. You want to maximise $S(\mathbf p)\equiv-\sum_i p_i \log p_i$ in the hyperplane $\sum_i p_i=1$. For this to be the case, $\nabla_{\mathbf p} S$ needs to be proportional to $\nabla_{\mathbf p}(\sum_i p_i-1)=\sum_i \hat{\mathbf e}_i$. This means that, for some $\lambda$, you have
$$
  - (\log p_i + 1) = \lambda,
$$
and thus $p_i=e^{-1-\lambda}$. Imposing $\sum_i p_i=1$ then gives $N=e^{1+\lambda}$. We conclude that $p_i = 1/N$ for all $i$.

The case constraining the average energy can also be worked out, but now you are maximising $S(\mathbf p)$ in the intersection of the hyperplanes $\sum_i p_i=1$ and $\sum_i p_i E_i=E$. A variation of Lagrange multipliers can handle this more general case (and you get a distribution of the type $p_n\simeq e^{-\beta E_n}$).